# Call Lightning action when using Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-out

Is there a way to call Lightning actions when embedding Lightning Out in a page outside Salesforce. I wanna call my action or perhaps even set so attribute from script that is separate from Lightning component framework.

I know you can setup an event listener when using Lightning in Visualforce and setup listener in VF via `$A.eventService.addHandler`.

Is there something opposite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.postMessage** like it has been described in the following link: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html